# ADF : Call Table rows with wait and foreach dynamically

Tags: foreach, azure-data-factory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKOPl.png)I have a SQL Table which gets updated everyday with approx 1300 to 1400 records.
I have to lookup first 200 rows and perform for-each and wait.
After completion take the next 200 rows and perform the same.

So far I have manually checked the number of rows and built the Lookup - Foreach - Wait 6 or 7 times.

Is there a way to pick the rows dynamically and run for 200 rows at a time and after completion do the same again?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you do .

1. Add a Lookup which reads all the rows ( beware lookup has a  max range of 5K , but at 1400 you are safe for now )
2. Add FE loop and try to reference the output of the lookup as
   @activity('YourLookup activity').output.value.
3. Set the batch count as 200
4. [image: List item]
   5.Inside the FE you can put the logic as to what youw ant to do with the Lookup data .

Play around with this and you will be achieve what you intend to .

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, Foreach only takes 50 ( max) batch count.